# How can I log BTrace into file Using VisualVM

Tags: btrace

I found the method of logging BTrace output into file by using command with Btraceagent.
Are there anything else methods to do this via VisualVM without using command line?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. Feel free to file a RFE for the BTrace VisualVM integration.